# How I can make a file unexecutable in winapi?

Tags: c, winapi, executable

How I can make a file unexecutable in winapi ?
Something like quarantine in anti-viruses .
Is it possible or not ?
Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you overwrite the first two bytes of the file with something other than MZ it won't be recognised as an executable file any more.